# ¿Como puedo indicar al IIS 8 que la ruta por defecto a iniciar sea una en especifico?

Tags: windows, iis, dominio, windows-server

Necesito indicarle a mi IIS que debe iniciar una aplicación en una determinada ruta, por ejemplo mi dominio deria. midominio.cl, es ahi donde esta mi aplicación corriendo pero la aplicación tiene una ruta por default donde se inicia que es miurl/mi-sitio, entonces para acceder al index o a la aplicación, se debería ingresar la siguiente url -> midominio.cl/miurl/mi-sitio.

Es esta url final `midominio.cl/miurl/mi-sitio` la que quiero agregar en el IIS para que cuando ingresen solo con el dominio `midominio.cl` el servidor la redireccione automáticamente hacia la ruta `midominio.cl/miurl/mi-sitio`

¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

En la administración del sitio en IIS hay un opción para poder configurar lo que viene a ser el *default document* de tu sitio.

[image: Default Document]

Y ahí agrega la vista o archivo que quiere aparezca por defecto.